# Kony Publishing Service timeout

Tags: sockets, tomcat, service, publishing, temenos-quantum

**UPDATE**
OK, I have found out the reason for this issue is because Kony Server was not up and running. Although I know the issue, my problem now is that I cannot start Kony Server...
I have gone into the Kony application folder and attempted to 'start' the Kony Server command (I'm using Mac), but even after doing so, the server is still inaccessible.

**Original question below**

I’m in the middle of trying to publish my Kony services but I’m running into a strange issue.

My services are set up and testing correctly, I then ‘generate’ my services.

When I try to ‘publish services’, I get a timeout error:

> [12-08-2014 04:06:31]java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431) . . .

I have made sure that my IP address is filled in the project properties > Kony Server Details tab > Server Name/IP Address, and made sure port 8080 is filled in HTTP Port.

Also, when I try to visit http://:8080/admin,  connection times out.

I was publishing correctly at the Kony training course, but since I got back to the office, it's breaking. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with the IP configurations, but other than the above, I'm not sure where else to find out.

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
G

Answer (score 1):

Are there any process running that could be using the same port? If you installed Kony in the default directories on mac, you can post the tomcat logs with the errors. The local install of Kony uses tomcat as it's server. You should be able to find the logs for your instance in the following location:

/Applications/Kony/Kony_Server/tomcat-7.0.52/instance1/logs

This should help see why the server isn't starting and provide some guidance. If you are still lost, post the logs up.